# Schemes syntax extension throws a "proper list required" error

Tags: scheme

I am trying to use the Scheme [(afp primitives)](https://unity.homelinux.net/afp/code/afp/primitives.sld) library in Repl.it, just by copying all procedures in the main.scm. But some procedures do not seem to work. For example the `rec` procedure is defined like this:

```
(define-syntax rec
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((rec (name . variables) . body)
     (letrec ((name (lambda variables . body))) name))
    ((rec name expression)
     (letrec ((name expression)) name))))
```

When I just define it, the compiler throws following error:

```
proper list required for function application or macro use: (name . variables) []
```

As I am just starting to learn Scheme, I have no idea how to fix this. Could someone help me out?

---

**Edit** - This is the situation:

[image]

Comment: when you try to use it..... how? please copy-paste your interaction, i.e. your input and the (error) response from the REPL.

Comment: @WillNess: Added a picture. So with other words, just be defining the procedure the compiler error occurs.

Comment: what procedure are you defining? do you have any code of your own in the input source, besides the code you copied from the library? also, could you provide the link to your Repl.it entry?

Comment: No, I got no code of my own at the moment. The Repl.it is: https://repl.it/@Jacobvan6/Scheme-trials#main.scm.

Comment: your code works as is in DrRacket. it must be the repl.it. (?) [cf](https://repl.it/@WillNess1/Scheme-trials#main.scm) which also works in Racket but doesn't work in repl.it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshots, repl.it uses Biwa Scheme.

From [its list of features](https://www.biwascheme.org/doc/features.html)

> BiwaScheme does not have `syntax-rules` or `syntax-case`

So you can't use `syntax-rules` macros with it like you're trying. Have to find another approach to `rec` or use a different scheme.